# Python recursion not returning value

Tags: python, recursion, return-value

For some reason x in this code is not updating within the recursion. Shouldn't x update as I'm calling b(c) within a(y)? When x updates in b(c) but doesn't return to

```
global nested
def extract(nested,depth):
    y = depth[0]
    depth = depth[1:]
    extract = nested[y]
    newlist(extract)
    return depth
def newlist(x):
    nested = x
    return nested
def recursiveRef(nested,depth):
    """Return element from nested list
    list ->int
    """
    if len(depth) == 0:
        return nested
    else:
        return recursiveRef(nested,extract(nested,depth))
```

Comment: In some languages, you'd need `x = b(c)` not just `b(c)`. Not sure on python

Comment: You haven't defined `depth` anywhere (not initialized it, nor are you incrementing it).  Can you please update the code?

Comment: This code should not even execute, giving you NameError in your recursion(). If you use global variables, please specify so.

Comment: your code is quite obscure, can you provide a simpler (non) working version?

Comment: Why you need this, or just a few samples of input and expected output, would really help understand what you're doing.

Comment: Which functions are you referring to what saying **a(c)** and **b(y)**?  The question is very poorly worded.  Who upvoted it???

Comment: @MarkTolonen: The original [revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6001180/revisions) used those names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
def recursiveRef(nested,depth):
    """Return element from nested list
    list ->int
    """
    if len(depth) == 0:
        return nested
    else:
        return recursiveRef(nested[depth[0]],depth[1:])

print recursiveRef([[1,2,3],[4,[5,6],7]],[1])
print recursiveRef([[1,2,3],[4,[5,6],7]],[1,1])
print recursiveRef([[1,2,3],[4,[5,6],7]],[1,1,1])
```

#### Output

```
[4, [5, 6], 7]
[5, 6]
6
```

Comment: Yes that is what i want to do

Answer (score 1):

I am not a `Python` master but I think the problem is that `x` is local to the recursion function. You are changing an other global `x` in your `b(c)`. Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks suspicious. When you think you want a global variable, usually you want a class. Consider wrapping your functions in a class and use self.x instead of x.

That said, "global" should not be written in the top of your program. Instead, you need it in every function that modifies your global variable, but not those that only reads it.

```
def newlist(x):
    global nested
    nested = x
    return nested
```

Answer (score 0):

The `x` variable in the `b` function is not binded to the one in the `recursion` function.

I really don't understand what you are tring to do -- I can be wrong but I suggest you to consider to put the two functions `a` and `b` into `recursion`, creating a **closure**.
In that way the nested functions can see and modify all the variables defined in the outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

An even simpler non-recursive version:

```
def inTree(tree, ref):
    for offs in ref:
        tree = tree[offs]
    return tree
```